# How to stop rspec from running test unit at the end?

Tags: rspec, testunit

Rspec tries to run Test::Unit tests at the end of running any spec file or whole test suite. It's still okay as I don't have any test unit test files but it tries to pass on the command line options given to rspec as they are to Test::Unit which results in

```
Finished in 0.54616 seconds
7 examples, 0 failures
invalid option: -O
Test::Unit automatic runner.
Usage: /usr/local/bin/rspec [options] [-- untouched arguments]

-r, --runner=RUNNER              Use the given RUNNER.
                                 (c[onsole], f[ox], g[tk], g[tk]2, t[k])
-n, --name=NAME                  Runs tests matching NAME.
                                 (patterns may be used).
-t, --testcase=TESTCASE          Runs tests in TestCases matching TESTCASE.
                                 (patterns may be used).
-I, --load-path=DIR[:DIR...]     Appends directory list to $LOAD_PATH.
-v, --verbose=[LEVEL]            Set the output level (default is verbose).
                                 (s[ilent], p[rogress], n[ormal], v[erbose])
    --                           Stop processing options so that the
                                 remaining options will be passed to the
                                 test.
-h, --help                       Display this help.

Deprecated options:
    --console                    Console runner (use --runner).
    --gtk                        GTK runner (use --runner).
    --fox                        Fox runner (use --runner).
```

How do I stop rspec from running test unit tests?

Versions of test gems I'm using are

```
gem 'rspec', '~> 2.7'
gem 'rspec-instafail'
gem 'ci_reporter'
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.7'
gem 'shoulda', :require => false # 2.3.3
gem 'factory_girl', '~> 2.6.4'
gem 'rr'
gem 'timecop'
gem 'rcov'
gem 'database_cleaner'
gem 'webmock', '~> 1.9.3'
gem 'vcr'
gem 'fakeweb', '~> 1.3.0'
gem 'spork', '~> 0.8.0'
gem 'webrat'
```

Answer (score 0):

[this page](http://www.jonathanleighton.com/articles/2012/stop-test-unit-autorun/) has an answer to your question

a temporary workaround is to set Test::Unit.run to true in your env.rb file:

```
Test::Unit.run = true
```